# Is there anyway to match name and number?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

For each client we have, we associate their name with an ID number in a database. However, we sign people in by name. I am trying to convert the names into their ID number in a spreadsheet.

I have a list of all the names and corresponding IDs. I realize that I could hard code it so that it would look something like:

```
 for (i=0; i < 31; i++) {
     if name = 'john doe'
        id = 256589
      elseif name = 'jane doe'
        id = 248352...}
```

and repeat that for each client. I've tested with a couple names and this solution does work. Since we don't have that many individuals come in it wouldn't be impossible to just repeat it. However, I would like to know if there are any shortcuts available.

Comment: fyi you can do it without script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you're doing this lookup.

This looks like script so you could use an object with the names as keys:

```
function getIdFromName(name) {
  // list of all employees and ids
  let employees = {
    "john doe": 256589,
    "jane doe": 248352
  }

  if (employees[name]) {
    return employees[name]
  } else {
    // this covers the case if name not found
    return false
  } 
}

// in rest of your code
var id = getIdFromName(name)
```

If you want to do the lookup in the sheet, you can use a lookup table containing names and ids then use VLOOKUP/INDEX(MATCH()) to find the corresponding ID

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realize I could do it within the sheet, so INDEX was exactly what I was looking for. If I were to continue using something like the script example you gave, would all I have to do to add someone new would be to add them to the list of employees?

Comment: If you use INDEX, make sure you use a named range or a big enough range to allow for future expansion (you don't want to update all formulas to change range from A1:B20 -> A1:B21). 
If you use the script, yep, you'd need to just add names to the employees object. If there's any chance someone else is going to be adding names, I'd suggest using the INDEX version - people tend to understand sheets better than script.